# urls from gsub not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some problems when I try to check urls after I get them using the gsub method.

From the console  it works fine:

```
('http://ale.it' =~ URI::regexp).nil?.to_s
=> "false"
```

but if i launch this it doesn't work:

```
"http://ale.it".gsub(/http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]+/, ('\0' =~ URI::regexp).nil?.to_s)   
=> "true"
```

How can I get correct urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved with:

```
"http://ale.it".gsub(/http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]+/) do |m|
 (m =~ URI::regexp).nil?.to_s) 
end
```

Comment: Am glad you solved it but am still not totally clear what you were trying to do :)

Answer (score 3):

*This is an explanation of what your 2 examples do. Whilst it isn't really an answer it's a bit long to fit in a comment.*

`=~` returns the position where a match occurs or `nil` if no match is found.

In your first example 'http://ale.it' matches `URI::regexp` starting at position 0 so you get `0.nil?` which is false, converted to a string "false"

`gsub` in your second example takes 2 parameters, a pattern and a replacement string and replaces all matches of the pattern with the replacement.

'\0' doesn't match `URI::regexp` so `('\0' =~ URI::regexp).nil?` is true and with `to_s` applied is the string "true".

"http://ale.it" matches `/http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]+/` so gets replaced with "true".

You will have to expand your question to explain what you're trying to achieve.